# How to unbind a function from an event among multiple functions?

Tags: javascript

Say for example, we don't know how many functions already binded to an event. In that case we can bind our own function like below

```
var old = (element.onclick) ? element.onclick : function () {};
element.onclick = function () {old(); myOwn()};
```

Now how to unbind myOwn function alone without disturbing others?

Comment: that's the reason why Event Listeners were implemented, so that you can attach and detach multiple handlers attached to an element.

Answer (score 3):

When attaching multiple events to a DOM element, you should not change the "onfoo" attribute. Rather, use `addEventListener("foo")` (or `attachEvent("foo")` in IE). Similarly, you have `removeEventListener` (`detachEvent` in IE) to remove events.

```
var myEventHandler = function (e) {
  alert("do stuff");
}

var myDomElement = document.getElementById("my_id");

myDomElement.addEventListener("click", myEventHandler, true);
myDomElement.attachEvent("click", myEventHandler); // IE

myDomElement.removeEventListener("click", myEventHandler, true);
myDomElement.detachEvent("click", myEventHandler); // IE
```

Replace "onfoo" with "foo". So when you do `element.onmouseup`, you should instead do `element.addEventListener("mouseup", ...)`.

It is imperative that you use a function reference, since the internal object ID of the function is used for reference, and not it's contents. This will not work:

```
myDomElement.addEventListener("click", function () { alert("foo") }, true)
myDomElement.removeEventListener("click", function () { alert("foo") }, true)
```

You can create a simple wrapper for cross browser compatibility.

```
var addEventListener = function (element, event, func) {
  if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(event, func, true);
  } else {
    element.attachEvent(event, func);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to suggest an edit for 1 symbol, but there is one typo in your answer: `detatchEvent ` instead of `detachEvent`.

Comment: Fixed, thanks! (And I had to write some more characters here, since "fixed, thanks!" was too short.)

Comment: Oh, sorry! It seems, my English is not so good. What I really meant that `detachEvent` is the correct version of ms event. We can check it in the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741346(v%3Dvs.85)

Comment: Hah! Thanks for following up on that! Fixed :)